# Find path to file that required this one

Tags: ruby

I'll show an example of what I'm trying to do.

#### child.rb

```
require 'parent'
class Child < Parent
  ...
end
```

#### parent.rb

```
class Parent 
  puts __FILE__
  ...
end
```

running this (e.g. in IRB):

```
require 'child'
child=Child.new
```

returns this:

```
/path/to/parent.rb
```

but i'm really trying to get the file `child.rb` instead.

How can i do this without moving the `puts __FILE__` in to the child class directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in Ruby to get what you are asking for. Perhaps if you explained why you want this—what you are trying to accomplish—then I (or someone else) could help you further. As it stands you seem to be asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Although it's not always the "file that required me", you can use `$0` in this case instead of `__FILE__` to get "the root file that is running" in the case when you have done `ruby parent.rb`. Note that this will not work with IRB, however. (Inside IRB `$0` is always "irb" or something equally unhelpful.)

Comment: this worked great and you were right about $0 showing up diff in irb.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `require` to output `caller_locations.first.absolute_path` before calling the original `require`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some backtrace method like `caller_locations(1,1)[0].path` or `caller`